# java URL access I/O error

Tags: java, url, ioexception

I am learning java. I've tried to access a website and see how many characters are there. A website I tried is:
http://cs.armstrong.edu/liang/data/Lincoln.txt
I get a I/O error: no such file output. but I shouldn't get since the web site is up & running.

```
package ikinciHaftam;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadFileFromURL {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.print("Enter a URL: ");
        Scanner inURL = new Scanner(System.in);
        String URLString = inURL.next();
        inURL.close();
        try{
            URL url = new URL(URLString);
            int count =0;
            Scanner input = new Scanner(url.openStream());
            System.out.println(url.openStream());
            while (input.hasNext()){
                String line = input.nextLine();
                count += line.length();
            }
            System.out.println("The file size is " + count + " characters");
            input.close();
        }
        catch(MalformedURLException ex){
            System.out.println("Malformed url");
        }
        catch(IOException e){               
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

and I get:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: cs.armstrong.edu
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
    at ikinciHaftam.ReadFileFromURL.main(ReadFileFromURL.java:18)
```

Comment: You're assuming that `IOException` means that the file doesn't exist, but you're wrong. Put `e.printStackTrace();` in the catch block and see what the **real** problem is.